# How to add description to photo using imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation

I'd like to add descriptions to this photo:

[image]

so that it look like this:

[image]

The command that I use is:

```
montage -pointsize 14 -gravity NorthWest  -title "\nName: $filename\nOrigin:$origin \n Price:$price "  input.png output.png
```

But instead I get:

How can I fix this? I need the description to appear on top left in a fringe not more than 20% the overall height of the image?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
name="Flower"
origin="Moon"
price="£3.99"
magick flower.jpg -size "%[fx:w/4]x%[fx:h/4]" caption:"Name: $name\nOrigin: $origin\nPrice:$price" -trim +swap -append result.jpg
```

[image]